# componentWillUnmount is not getting invoked

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, reactjs

I have a backbone application, where i am trying to integrate React components.

React component is mounted using following code :
`ReactDOM.render(
 <WrappedComponent />, node
);`
where node is the DOM mode. This way React lifecycle events like componentWillMount and componentDidMount are getting called fine.

But when routing happen through Backbone routing, and React component getting removed from DOM,  componentWillUnmount is not invoked.

Any solutions ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`componentWillUnmount` does not get called automatically when the container node gets removed. It only gets called:

1. At the top level, when you call [`ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdom.unmountcomponentatnode)
2. As child components, when the parent unmounts the component

Comment: Today i realized that if we cant read entire library we are using, at least we should read entire documentation for that.